# what does "this" keyword mean in the initializer block?

Tags: java, this

Here is my code:

```
class StaticBlock {
    {       
        println("initializer block : " + message);
    }
    public StaticBlock(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    private String message;
}
```

Now the issue is that, in the initializer block

```
{       
    println("initializer block : " + message);
}
```

if I add the `this` keyword before `message`, it works, but there is an error when missing `this` keyword.

And the compiler says:

```
StaticBlockDemo.java:34: illegal forward reference
                println("initializer block : " + message);
                                                 ^
1 error
```

Why aren't they the same?

Comment: 'this',I perhaps it means 'current' instance,but here,it seems confused for me.

Comment: Those "duplicates" are not actually the same question, if you read more than the summary...

Comment: I agree, those duplicates are not actually duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the design rationale, but it may help to read the relevant sections of the Java language specification.

[**8.6. Instance Initializers**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6)

> Instance initializers are permitted to refer to the current object via the keyword `this` (§15.8.3), to use the keyword `super` (§15.11.2, §15.12), and to use any type variables in scope.
>
> Use of instance variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these instance variables are in scope. See §8.3.2.3 for the precise rules governing forward reference to instance variables.

[**8.3.2.3. Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3)

> The declaration of a member needs to appear textually before it is used only if the member is an instance (respectively `static`) field of a class or interface `C` and all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The usage occurs in an instance (respectively `static`) variable initializer of `C` or in an instance (respectively static) initializer of `C`.
> - The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.
> - The usage is via a simple name.
> - `C` is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.

Here's the example from that section of the spec trimmed down to illustrate the specific point you're asking about:

```
class UseBeforeDeclaration {

    {
        j = 200;
          // ok - assignment
        j = j + 1;
          // error - right hand side reads before declaration
        int k = j = j + 1;
          // error - illegal forward reference to j
        int n = j = 300;
          // ok - j at left hand side of assignment
        int h = j++;
          // error - read before declaration
        int l = this.j * 3;
          // ok - not accessed via simple name
    }

    int j;
}
```

I should also note, though, that even the compiling version of your code isn't going to do what you want. If you run it:

```
new StaticBlock("abc");
```

It will print

```
initializer block : null
```

This is because initializers are executed before (most of) the constructor body. Here are the salient points from the spec:

[**12.5. Creation of New Class Instances**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

> *[...]* the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:
>
> *[...]*
>
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class *[...]*
>
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. *[...]*

Comment: thank you,actually,you were right,and I defined the instance variable 'message' out of the scope initializer blocks and it was unreachable unless I use the key word 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

> if I add 'this' keyword before 'message',it works,but error when missing 'this' keyword. why they aren't the same?

`this` keyword points to current instance of the class.

```
public StaticBlock(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

Here if you don't use `this` then it will assign the value of `message` local variable because scope of the local variable is more than instance in a block.

When you use the `this` then it will assign the variable value of the current object variable.

Comment: in the stack,the statement 'StaticBlock(String message)' does create a   variable 'message',isn't it?What confused me was that,in common non-static method,we can reference to the instance variable even though not using 'this'.don't you think they aren't similar?

Comment: It creates the local variable named `message`, here if you don't use the this that would assign the same value to same local variable.  "What confused me was that,in common non-static method,we can reference to the instance variable even though not using 'this'.don't you think they aren't similar?" -- You can but you must have different name of local and instance variable. Here you have both same `message`

Answer (score 0):

If there is clash between local variable name and instance member name, then `this` keyword will compiler tell to use object variable.

Comment: 'class variable'? isn't it should be 'instance variable'?I confused because in the non-static method,it works the same whether 'this' exist or not,I mean that,it is not essential,isn't it?

Comment: Well, yes, you are right, variable that belons to object. I will update it to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of having classes in Java is that you can model objects as a class, and you can create multiple instances of an object (in most cases).

In order to reference information that is specific to a single object class, we can use the `this` inside the object (class) code. It tells the program that you want to make use of the `current` objects variables and values. By using `this.message = message`, you are assigning the value of message that has been passed into the function and storing it in the object's message variable.

There are scope aspects to this, where `message` has a local scope, and `this.message` has the scope over the whole object. This is why when you tried to call on message in your print code: `println("initializer block : " + message);`, a local variable message didn't exist within the scope of this function.

Comment: thank you,actually,you were right,and I defined the instance variable 'message' out of the scope initializer blocks and it was unreachable unless I use the key word 'this'.